# Excel - Systematically Referring to Sheets on iPad-version

Tags: ios, excel, ipad, excel-formula, vba

I have an Excel document in which I would like to refer to the previous sheet in the present sheet systematically. Of course, I could type the name of the previous sheet directly into the formula in every sheet of the document, but that is way too impractical. 
I have tried using VBA/macros to create a function that refers to the previous sheet successfully on a PC, but this does not work on an iPad.

That leads to the actual question: is there any smart way to systematically and automatically refer to the previous sheet (in any sheets except the first one) on the iPad-version of Excel?

Note: I excuse if this have been asked before, but I have searched thoroughly without any worthful answers.